# "Error when converting the nvarchar value "--" to the int-data type."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I haven't been working with SQL for that long because I'm still relatively new to the world of IT specialists. Currently I'm working on a report for an automated documentation and get the following error

> Error when converting the nvarchar value "--" to the int-data type.

```
select tAccounts.*
from tAccounts, tDomains, tADSDocu
where tAccounts.AccountID = tDomains.AccountID
and tDomains.DomainID = tADSDocu.DomainID and tAccounts.AccountName = {PrimaryKey}
```

I've only recently started with SQL.

Comment: You should also use modern explicit join rather than that old style implicit joins.

Comment: Also, given that there's no `--` in the posted code snippet and given the field names you are joining, it seems like this may not be all of the code or not the code that's giving you the error. Unless of course the `AccountID` or `DomainID` types don't match on the joins you are using, or the `PrimaryKey` placeholder doesn't match the data type of the `AccountName` field, but the fieldnames give a guess as to the types and this seems unlikely...

Comment: "--" was replaced in the error message
Before there was a name of a customer ^^
In Germany we say "Datenschutz".

Comment: @Merseburger
try something like this

SELECT ta.* FROM tAccounts ta
JOIN tDomains  td ON ta.AccountID = td.AccountID
JOIN tADSDocu tdc ON td.DomainID = tdc.DomainID
WHERE ta.AccountName = 'your primary key value'

also ensure that there is no cast error

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You're comparing a `(n)varchar` value to an `int` *somewhere*, I assume in the implicit JOIN in your `WHERE`. If so, seems you need to fix the design and ensure the 2 columns are the same data type, and remove any bad data (as `'--'` isn't a valid `int` value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the AccountName field is nvarchar and your PrimaryKey is int, that's why this may occur, maybe something like this might work;

```
select tAccounts.*
from tAccounts, tDomains, tADSDocu
where tAccounts.AccountID = tDomains.AccountID
and tDomains.DomainID = tADSDocu.DomainID and tAccounts.AccountName = '{PrimaryKey}'
```

Comment: And what about "AccountID"?
I would have to come to the same result.

Comment: i assumed the AccountID and DomainID parts have the same data type, but if they don't they might cause problems either